# XSLT Delete whole tag if subtag with certain value presents

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml:

```xml
<root>
    <product>
        <some-another-tag>45</some-another-tag>
        <provider>1</provider>
    </product>
    <product>
        <some-another-tag>45</some-another-tag>
        <provider>2</provider>
    </product>
    <product>
        <some-another-tag>45</some-another-tag>
        <provider>3</provider>
    </product>
    <product>
        <some-another-tag>45</some-another-tag>
        <provider>1</provider>
    </product>
    <product>
        <some-another-tag>45</some-another-tag>
        <provider>8</provider>
    </product>
</root>
```

Using xsl transform I want to remove whole `<product>` tag if there is `<provider>1</provider>` in it.

How can I build such template?

Comment: Do you want to remove `product` elements if they have a `<provider>1</provider>` child element?

Comment: @MartinHonnen correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to remove certain elements then you start with the identity transformation template and add empty templates matching those elements you want to remove, see http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpk which does:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product[provider = 1]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick however if I have more another inner tag it wont delete whole product tag. Like if I want to delete product in case it has product/provider[type=1]

Comment: If you use `<xsl:template match="product[provider/type = 1]"/>` the `product` elements having a `provider` child with a `type` grand child being `1` are removed. An alternative is using `match="product[provide[type = 1]]"`.