# xslt select any of tags in match

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <element>
        <prop>
            <value>1</value>
        </prop>
        <prop>
            <value>1</value>
        </prop>
        <prop>
            <value>2</value>
        </prop>
    </element>
</root>
```

How can I refer to ANY `<prop>` element in match?

I can do for example something like

```
<xsl:template match="element[prop[3][value != 2]]"/>
```

but I need something like

`<xsl:template match="element[prop[ANY][value != 2]]"/>`

UPD

Example:

```
  <root>
    <Product>
        <somefield>123</somefield>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Some ID</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>964067</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Good</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>25</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <somefield>123</somefield>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Some ID</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>964067</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Good</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>11</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <somefield>123</somefield>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Some ID</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>964067</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Good</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>26</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
    </Product>
</root>
```

As can be seen there are few ProductIdentifier tags in Product. I want to get ONLY products with IDValue = 25 OR IDValue = 26 in IDTypeName = Good

So the result xml will be

```
<root>
    <Product>
        <somefield>123</somefield>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Some ID</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>964067</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Good</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>25</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <somefield>123</somefield>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Some ID</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>964067</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductIdentifier>
            <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
            <IDTypeName>Good</IDTypeName>
            <IDValue>26</IDValue>
        </ProductIdentifier>
    </Product>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get ONLY products with IDValue = 25 OR IDValue = 26 in
>   IDTypeName = Good

As you have learned in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917212/xslt-delete-whole-tag-if-subtag-with-certain-value-presents), it is best to start with the *indentity transform* template, and exclude the nodes that do **not** satisfy the condition:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Product[not(ProductIdentifier[(IDValue=25 or IDValue=26) and IDTypeName='Good'])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had trouble to build this not condition